# React Native app stuck on blank screen when running on device with remote debugging

Tags: react-native

I run my react native application on my device (iPhone 6) and it loads fine. But when I enable remote debugging, it seems to connect fine to debugger but gets stuck on a blank screen.

As soon as I turn off remote debugging, everything loads fine.

I am on react-native 0.40.0.

Please help!

Comment: Do you use Chrome as debugger? It happens to me when I use the app "React Native Debugger" and I have to restart the debugger before it works again.

Comment: I have the same "white screen issue" but with Nuclide debugger and maybe there is some connection with this issue but I am not sure. For more info see [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154551/react-native-app-stuck-on-blank-white-screen-with-remote-debugging-using-nuclide).

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons, in my case it was the cache that was creating problem.
Suggested Solutions:-

1. Clean gradlew
       - To clean gradle go to android folder and open cmd in it, run '`gradlew clean`' in the cmd
2. after cleaning gradle, re-build your app run command (run-android etc)
3. if the problem exist after rebuilding follow step 4 & 5
4. Go to App's setting and clear App's data
5. now clear react-native terminal's cache ( `react-native start --reset-cache` )

These steps will fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I overcome this effect by doing the following:

1. go to the terminal and press "a" to reopen Android device or emulator
2. close application on mobile device and open it once again
3. if necessary, restart R to restart packager and clear cache in the terminal

Comment: I tried this with my Android connected over USB.  I can't even exit the application without killing Expo.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue when launching a react native module from iOS native module.

Replacing below mentioned code using BUNDLE URL

```
    if let bundleUrl = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.bridge?.bundleURL {
    let mockData:NSDictionary = ["names":
        [
            ["name":"Name 1",],
            ["name":"Name 2"]
        ]
    ]
    
    let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: bundleUrl, moduleName: "modulename", initialProperties: mockData as [NSObject : AnyObject], launchOptions: nil)
    
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view = rootView
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with this updated code using BRIDGE

```
    if let bridge = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.bridge {
    let mockData:NSDictionary = ["names":
        [
            ["name":"Name 1",],
            ["name":"Name 2"]
        ]
    ]
    
    let rootView = RCTRootView(bridge: bridge, moduleName: "modulename", initialProperties: mockData as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view = rootView
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

resolve the issues!!